# SQLite syntax for operator “ANY”

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, any

I'm trying execute this query in SQLite:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
WHERE rating = ANY
      (SELECT rating
       FROM customers
       WHERE city = 'Rome');
```

But received this error:

```
Query Error: near "SELECT": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

If I replace 
    `rating = ANY`
 to `rating IN`, everything works fine.

Can someone show me how **ANY** statement works in SQLite and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK, SQLite doesn't have an `ANY` operator. You could, however, use the `IN` operator to get the required functionality:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customers 
WHERE  rating IN -- Here!
       (SELECT rating
        FROM   customers
        WHERE  city = 'Rome');
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is no `ANY` keyword in SQLite, therefore it won't work.